# Renaming published WCF service library URL for consuming apps

Tags: asp.net, wcf, service-name

I have a WCF service library project that I publish to a IIS hosted folder. After publishing, a svc is created in the folder and is consumed with a URL like this:

http://mysite.com/services/This.Is.My.Namespace.ServiceClassName.svc

How can I set this up so that I can use a friendly service name that doesn't let others know the namespace / class name used in my project?

In the web.config, does the service name have to exactly match up with the namespace + class name?

Perhaps I should have created WCF service applications instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the file. If you edit the file as text, you will see the namespace it uses.